# How to make CSS visible only for Android phone UC browser

Tags: android, css, user-agent

Is there a way to make some CSS rules visible only for Android phone UC browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article: [CSS: User Agent Selectors](http://rog.ie/blog/html5-boilerplate-addon)

Basically, when you use this script:

```
var b = document.documentElement;
b.setAttribute('data-useragent',  navigator.userAgent);
b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform );
b.className += ((!!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window))?' touch':'');
```

You can now use CSS to target any browser / version.

So for Android UC, I took a look [here](http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/browser212364/uc-browser) to see the user agent strings for Android UC and they all contained the text 'UCBrowser' so we can do the following:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qn63n/63/)**

```
html[data-useragent*='UCBrowser'] .someRules
{
    visibility: visible;/* or display:block etc */
}
```

Comment: I think this is the closest you'll get to a css solution